# PyGame Menu Formatting

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, pygame

So I've been recently working on programming a game in Python as well as an external library called PyGame.  If anyone is familiar with the game Hearthstone, that is sort of the feel I'm going for.  However, that is besides the point.  I have already researched how to display images and their positions, and I have been stuck trying to figure out to create a menu with buttons in the PyGame UI.  I have previously programmed in Visual Basic, and I was wondering if the PyGame interface allowed for system event detection in general, not unlike Visual Basic (i.e. mouse clicks, key presses).  Help would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you've "researched how to display images and their position", well, a menu with buttons is exactly that. Of course, there is an event system, read the documentation of PyGame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to make a `while` loop to have event detection in pygame. Here is an example:

```
import time

while 1:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      #happens when 'X' in window is clicked
      #put code to be executed here
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      onclick_function(pygame.mouse.get_pos) 
      #passes mouse position as tuple to function to deal with click control.
```

When blitting images to the display, one needs to know coordinates. Simply keep a list of `Rect` objects, each with a function to execute when they are clicked, and use a function to iterate through the list and see if the coordinates of the mouse are inside the `Rect`.

See the links for blitting images to the display:

Links:

-`Rect`: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect

-`Surface`: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface

-`image`: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if the PyGame interface allowed for system event detection in general, not unlike Visual Basic

Short answer: no. Pygame is not event driven. You'll have to write everything yourself, since pygame is just a small wrapper around SDL with some extra features.

Maybe take a look at [cocos2d](http://python.cocos2d.org/) or [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/), which offer such event loops.